Is there a way to remove /r/n in a Logic Apps liquid template?
I have a json that is returning:
"Product: Refrigerator\r\nBrand: Frigidaire\r\nWarranty Info: Service Contract\r\nModel (Optional):"

I need to remove \r\n and replace it with a string. I can't for the life of me figure it out.
I have tried dozens of combinations of | Escape | escape,
"purchase_date": "{{ record.description | Remove: '\\' }}",
"purchase_date": "{{ record.description | Remove: '\\r\\n' }}",
"purchase_date": "{{ record.description | Remove: '\\r\n' }}",

What am I missing?

Try using Replace instead of Remove.
The following transformation worked for me:
{
  "purchase_date": "{{ content.record.description | Replace: '\r\n', '' }}"
}

Result:

